# Sort array of objects based on an array

Tags: javascript, arrays, ecmascript-6

I'd like to sort top level objects of the given array by the most-nested value (that is 'outcome') AND the 'gameType'. Sorting by 'gameType' is set by user, who inputs array of values in specific order, e.g. [201, 202, 249] (length of the input is not fixed). 'gameType' outside of range given by user is ignored and pushed to the end of the result. Sorting by 'outcome' happens by selecting biggest value out of available outcomes.

Here is a function for sorting outcomes:

```
outcomes => Math.max(...outcomes.sort(({ outcome: a }, { outcome: b }) => a - b).map(({ outcome }) => outcome))
```

And here is the array:

```
[
  {
    "eventId": 513221,
    "games": [
      {
        "gameId": 31313404,
        "gameType": 240,
        "outcomes": [
          {
            "outcome": 1.8
          }, {
            "outcome": 21
          }, {
            "outcome": 2
          }
        ]
      }, {
        "gameId": 31313413,
        "gameType": 201,
        "outcomes": [
          {
            "outcome": 2.1
          }, {
            "outcome": 2.6
          }, {
            "outcome": 4.1
          }
        ]
      }
    ]
  }, {
    "eventId": 513216,
    "games": [
      {
        "gameId": 31314456,
        "gameType": 249,
        "outcomes": [
          {
            "outcome": 1.45
          }, {
            "outcome": 40
          }, {
            "outcome": 2.5
          }
        ]
      }, {
        "gameId": 31314475,
        "gameType": 201,
        "outcomes": [
          {
            "outcome": 1.5
          }, {
            "outcome": 4.55
          }, {
            "outcome": 4.75
          }
        ]
      }
    ]
  }, {
    "eventId": 513263,
    "games": [
      {
        "gameId": 31314398,
        "gameType": 241,
        "outcomes": [
          {
            "outcome": 1.52
          }, {
            "outcome": 2.35
          }
        ]
      }, {
        "gameId": 31314423,
        "gameType": 201,
        "outcomes": [
          {
            "outcome": 1.65
          }, {
            "outcome": 3.9
          }, {
            "outcome": 4.25
          }
        ]
      }
    ]
  }, {
    "eventId": 5132631,
    "games": [
      {
        "gameId": 313143981,
        "gameType": 240,
        "outcomes": [
          {
            "outcome": 1.52
          }, {
            "outcome": 30
          }, {
            "outcome": 2.35
          }
        ]
      }, {
        "gameId": 313144231,
        "gameType": 202,
        "outcomes": [
          {
            "outcome": 1.65
          }, {
            "outcome": 3.9
          }
        ]
      }
    ]
  }, {
    "eventId": 5132632,
    "games": [
      {
        "gameId": 313143912,
        "gameType": 298,
        "outcomes": [
          {
            "outcome": 1.57
          }, {
            "outcome": 2.2
          }
        ]
      }, {
        "gameId": 313144232,
        "gameType": 202,
        "outcomes": [
          {
            "outcome": 1.65
          }, {
            "outcome": 4.11
          }
        ]
      }
    ]
  }
]
```

Comment: do you have a practical example, which of the values goes into sorting?

Comment: that does not help. please add the wanted result and the input parameters for sorting - and what values are importent for the result.

Comment: Out of the all available gameType 201 games the highest outcome is 4.75, so the 513216 eventId should be in first place. Second one goes for eventId 513263 because it has 201 gameType with the highest outcome value of 4.25. Third is the 513221 as the last array item with 201 gameType.
Fourth place would be for eventId 5132632 because of gameType 202 with highest value of 4.11 which is higher than 5132631's 3.9

Comment: User input would be [201, 202] for the example result above

Answer (score 0):

You could take an object as helper for sorting. The properties are the index of the wanted `gameType` and the `max` value of `outcome` for each game.

```js
var data = [{ eventId: 513221, games: [{ gameId: 31313404, gameType: 240, outcomes: [{ outcome: 1.8 }, { outcome: 21 }, { outcome: 2 }] }, { gameId: 31313413, gameType: 201, outcomes: [{ outcome: 2.1 }, { outcome: 2.6 }, { outcome: 4.1 }] }] }, { eventId: 513216, games: [{ gameId: 31314456, gameType: 249, outcomes: [{ outcome: 1.45 }, { outcome: 40 }, { outcome: 2.5 }] }, { gameId: 31314475, gameType: 201, outcomes: [{ outcome: 1.5 }, { outcome: 4.55 }, { outcome: 4.75 }] }] }, { eventId: 513263, games: [{ gameId: 31314398, gameType: 241, outcomes: [{ outcome: 1.52 }, { outcome: 2.35 }] }, { gameId: 31314423, gameType: 201, outcomes: [{ outcome: 1.65 }, { outcome: 3.9 }, { outcome: 4.25 }] }] }, { eventId: 5132631, games: [{ gameId: 313143981, gameType: 240, outcomes: [{ outcome: 1.52 }, { outcome: 30 }, { outcome: 2.35 }] }, { gameId: 313144231, gameType: 202, outcomes: [{ outcome: 1.65 }, { outcome: 3.9 }] }] }, { eventId: 5132632, games: [{ gameId: 313143912, gameType: 298, outcomes: [{ outcome: 1.57 }, { outcome: 2.2 }] }, { gameId: 313144232, gameType: 202, outcomes: [{ outcome: 1.65 }, { outcome: 4.11 }] }] }],
    input = [201, 202],
    order = data.reduce((o, { eventId, games }) => {
        o[eventId] = games
            .map(({ gameType, outcomes }) => ({ index: input.indexOf(gameType), max: Math.max(...outcomes.map(({ outcome }) => outcome)) }))
            .filter(({ index }) => index !== -1)
            .reduce((a, b) => a.index < b.index ? a : b, { index: Infinity, max: -Infinity });
        return o;
    }, {});

data.sort((a, b) =>
    order[a.eventId].index - order[b.eventId].index ||
    order[b.eventId].max - order[a.eventId].max
);

console.log(data);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```